# How the GNU builtin function `__builtin_unreachable ` works in this code snippet?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, gnu

I have a code snippet in my project in which the `__builtin_unreachable` function has been used but I don't know why it is needed here.

And I read from [GNU __builtin_unreachable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), it seems that the `__builtin_unreachable` function is used to inform the compiler this line will never be reached during the CPU run time, so that a lot of complains in compilation can be prevented in advance. But I am not understood why this feature is needed in this code snippet, it seems nothing will happen by removing the `__builtin_unreachable`.

```
# define ATHCONTAINERS_ASSUME(x) do { if (!(x)) __builtin_unreachable(); } while(0)


inline
void*
AuxVectorData::Cache::getDataArray (SG::auxid_t auxid,
                                    AuxVectorData& parent)
{
  // This function is important for performance.
  // Be careful when changing it.

  void* ptr = cachePtr (auxid);
  if (ATHCONTAINERS_UNLIKELY (ptr == 0)) {
    // We don't have the variable cached.
    // Call the out-of-line routine to get it cached.
    ptr = parent.getDataOol (auxid, false);

    // These inform the compiler of what the previous call did.
    // They tell the optimizer that it can now assume that this cache
    // entry is valid.
    ATHCONTAINERS_ASSUME (ptr != 0); 
    ATHCONTAINERS_ASSUME (cachePtr (auxid) != 0); 
    ATHCONTAINERS_ASSUME (cachePtr (auxid) == ptr);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

Comment: It tells the compiler to pretend the expressions are never true. Most likely for optimization reasons. However, this looks like premature optimization to me.

Comment: _"so that a lot of complains in compilation can be prevented in advance"_ No, that's not what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

`ATHCONTAINERS_ASSUME` tells the compiler that its argument `x` cannot be false.  This relieves the compiler from having to generate any code to accommodate the possibility that `x` is false.  For example, when the compiler sees `ATHCONTAINERS_ASSUME (ptr != 0)` it can assume `ptr` is not null, and any code which contradicts that assumption can be optimized away, as it would be undefined behavior.

For example, since `getDataArray()` is `inline`, the compiler can know at every call site that the returned pointer will never be null.  So if a caller does this:

```
if (void* p = cache.getDataArray(aux, parent))
    memcpy(p, "OK", 2);
```

The compiler can generate code which directly writes "OK" without performing the null check.

Comment: does you mean that the compiler can pretend these expressions is `true` even outside this function?

Comment: @springcc: Yes, wherever the function's definition is visible.  In this case the function is defined as `inline`, so the call sites can see the definition.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty interesting, and new to me.

My best understanding, from the documentation you linked to which says:

> If control flow reaches the point of the `__builtin_unreachable()`, the program is undefined.

So basically the macro reaches undefined behavior if the condition is false. Thus, the compiler is assumed to be able to optimize based on the assumption that that doesn't happen, i.e. the conditions are not false.

I'd be interested in comparing the result from building the code with and without those macros, to further understand what actual difference it makes.

Relying on this to get some kind of optimization to happen seems kind of "brittle" to me, since it assumes a lot about the internal functioning of the compiler.

Comment: It's not that brittle. It is like dereferencing a pointer without checks for null pointers. Optimizers take advantage of UB like this all the time

Comment: `I'd be interested in comparing...` Unfortunately this is not possible due to some technical issue.

Comment: _"since it assumes a lot about the internal functioning of the compiler."_ Not really, it tells the compiler about invariants  of your program which it couldn't otherwise deduce. What the compiler does with that information is up to the compiler, but you don't need to care. It's not brittle, because an invariant of your program should always be true, whether the compiler makes use of it or not.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sure, I didn't mean brittle as in "might break", I meant that it's hard to rely on certain optimizations happening. I tried to clarify in the answer.

Comment: I still disagree. "This pointer is not null" is a pretty basic assertion that any optimizing compiler should be able to make use of, so there's nothing specific to the internals details of any single compiler. And nothing in the OP's question says the code _relies_ on any particular outcome from giving this additional info to the compiler, although it's certainly safe to rely on GCC understanding GCC's own builtin.

Answer (score 1):

As the code comment indicates, it tells stories to the optimizer.

The first thing this tells, is that the compiler can assume that the return value is not a null pointer. It would probably improve the readability of the code if another gcc extension would be used instead, namely 
`__attribute__((__returns_nonnull__))`. Adding this to the interface of `getDataArray` would also guarantee that property, even if the the compiler decides that he can't inline it for whatever reason.

But it is telling more than that. It also tells (or tries to tell) that future calls to `cachePtr` with the same parameter will return the same result.

All these properties would probably better be guaranteed by removing the unused `parent` parameter (to avoid aliasing analysis) and by also adding `__attribute__((__const__))` to `getDataArray`.